# How can I install ID3 support for PHP on Debian?

Tags: php, debian, apt, id3

I tried `apt-get install php-getid3` and it installs, but when I restart lighttpd and use `id3_get_tag()` in my script I get the following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function id3_get_tag() in x.php on line 3

I thought this was odd since usually the packages are `php5-gd` or `php5-mysql` and not just `php-`

I even tried installing the package `id3` as well and restarting lighttpd but that didn't work either.

I'd rather not have to compile PHP myself if it can be avoided.

Comment: Check the server logs. If the extension couldn't be loaded there has to be something about it in the logs.